# Notification Issue redirection in android studio

Tags: android

I have the notification Issues.
In app Push Notification Redirection Work Properly.
But App In background and Foreground Redirection Not Work Properly In Particular Activity.Its stop in HomeActivity.

Comment: post some code so we can help

Comment: MyFirebaseMessagingService Class

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("isFromHome", "true");
            intent.putExtra("from_noti", "true");
            intent.putExtra("app_screen", app_screen);

Comment: SplashActivity

@Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        displayIntentData();}

Comment: HomeActivity
if (intent != null) {
            strFrom = intent.getStringExtra("isFrom");
            url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
            view = intent.getStringExtra("view");
            from_dash = intent.getStringExtra("from_dash");
            isFromNotification = intent.getStringExtra("from_noti");     
            Debugger.debugE("fromcheckmto1", "" + isFromNotification);
            bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                isFromNotification = bundle.getString("from_noti");
            
            }

Comment: @HayssamSoussi any idea